# How do I get a thread dump of my Wildfly process on Amazon Linux?

Tags: linux, java, dump, threads, wildfly8

We're using Wildfly 11 with JDK 8 on Amazon Linux.  How do I get a thread dump of our Wildfly process?  We're trying to troubleshoot why we're seeing high CPU utilization for that process.  We do NOT have jstack installed so I thought I could use "kill -3", but it outputs nothing ...

```
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ ps -elf | grep java
0 S jboss     1574     1  0  80   0 - 28276 -      07:02 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/java/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml
0 S jboss     1617  1574  1  80   0 - 994904 -     07:02 ?        00:09:18 /usr/java/default/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/java/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/java/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /usr/java/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/java/wildfly/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/java/wildfly -Djboss.server.base.dir=/usr/java/wildfly/standalone -c standalone.xml
0 S 602       3777  3748  0  80   0 - 27619 -      15:24 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto java
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ 
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ 
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ sudo kill -QUIT 1574
[myuser@mymachine ~]$
```

Any help is appreciated, -

Answer (score 0):

The PID is incorrect. Try

sudo kill -QUIT 1617

That's the java process that parent PID (1574) started